# Equity protection and butterfly certificates pricing

Tags: options, fixed-income, pricing

Certificates issued by famous industry names are usually made up by a combination of a fixed income instrument and some vanilla and exotic options.

I am looking for something which explains:

- how to decompose a certificate in its derivatives instruments (e.g. "A *XYZ* certificate is usually made up by a zero coupon bond, a down & out Put striked ad $D$ and a vanilla Call striked at $K$);
- some suitable pricing strategies (e.g. pricing single instruments and then sum up NPVs to obtain current NPV of certificate).

In particular, my focus would be on these types: **Equity protection** and **Butterfly** certificates.

Do you know any good source for such material? Internet offers a lot of "easy" stuff to explain how these instruments work from a purely qualitative point of view ([**this**](http://www.my-structured-products.com/Capital-Guarantee/capital-guarantee-without-cap) site, as instance), but it lacks of well organized quantitative material for pricing purposes.